# Fleck WebSocket sends duplicate messages back to client

Tags: c#, websocket

Connecting to the Flec WebSocket server my client will receive the same message that was sent correctly the first time. The next time a message is sent, Fleck will send back the same message 2 times. Next time 3 times, and so on. I have tried different clients with the same result. Any idea why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Fleck;

namespace Websocket

{

    class Program

    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection> ();
            var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://localhost:8081");
            server.Start(socket =>
            {

              socket.OnOpen = () => allSockets.Add(socket);

              socket.OnClose = () => allSockets.Remove(socket);

              socket.OnMessage = message =>

              {

                  foreach (var s in allSockets.ToList())

                      socket.Send(message);

                  Console.WriteLine(message);

              };

             });

            var input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not the code posted.  You must be adding the receive message to the send message some place in the code.

Comment: It is the server side code.

Comment: I can't tell from the code posted how to fix issue.  It is probably in the interface IWebSocketConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side I had the OnMessage inside a while loop.
Problem solved